# telerik:RadWindow IE issue

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik

I'd want to show RadWindow2. It shows in Chrome, Mozilla but in IE9 and IE10 don't show. How to solve this issue?

js

```
function Show() 
{
    var oWnd = $find("<%= RadWindow2.ClientID %>");
    oWnd.show();
}
```

aspx

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onClientclick="Show()">Change
 </asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) make sure you are cancelling the postback:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
OnClientclick="Show(); return false;">Change
 </asp:LinkButton>
```

2) make sure you use a version that supports IE9 and IE10. That would be Q1 2011 and Q3 2012 respectively. Otherwise you would get a JS error.